# Hibernate spatial and PostGIS with WildFly 8

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgis, wildfly-8, hibernate-spatial

I'm migrating from Glassfish4 to WildFly8 application server and get the following error:

```
Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
```

I am using Hibernate Spatial and PostGIS. For the Glassfish server I added the postgis jar to the /lib/ext folder to fix that error.

I followed the steps in this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/bjornharrtell/3054462, but it doesn't work for me, i.e. I added these modules to /org/hibernate/main :

```
hibernate-spatial-4.3.jar
resource-root path="jts-1.13.jar
```

and these entries to modules.xml:

```
<resource-root path="hibernate-spatial-4.3.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jts-1.13.jar"/>
...
<module name="org.postgresql"/>
```

and to /org/postgresql/main:

```
postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar
postgis-jdbc-1.5.3.jar
```

full modules.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="postgis-jdbc-1.5.3.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

I also tried just adding the jars to WEB-INF/lib, but when I add 'Dependencies:  org.postgresql export' to MANIFEST.MF, I get:

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.postgresql:main
```

Any ideas how I can get the postgis, hibernate-spatial, etc. classes all loaded correctly?

Cheers,
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Found a similar setup to my server at: https://github.com/opennucleus/opennucleus and I looked at the differences. Turns out in standalone.xml I should have put:

```
<driver name="postgresql-driver" module="org.postgresql">
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
```

instead of:

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
   <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Now it all works fine!